# JavaScript: generate table column per column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm new to coding and I'm really stuck. Here's the situation: I made a script to generate a unique table from multiple text areas, and that’s working fine. The problem is that I need to fill the table in a specific way:

- data from 1st textarea=1st Column
- data from 2nd textarea=2nd Column
- data from 3rd textarea=3rd Column

(but all the columns need to be part of the same table)
Right now all the data from the 3 textAreas appears one below the other(in rows, not columns) and I just can’t figure it out.

**So far, that's my script:**

```
<script>
function generateTable() {

$('textarea').each(function(){

  var data = $(this).val(); console.log(data);
  var rows = data.split("\n");
  var table = $('<table />');

    for(var y in rows) {
        var cells = rows[y].split("\t");
        var row = $('<tr />');
        for(var x in cells) {
            row.append('<td>'+cells[x]+'</td>');
        }
        table.append(row);
    }
    $('#excel_table1').append(table);
})
}
</script>
```

**That’s my “body” with the text areas in divs:**

```
<div id=street>   <p>street:</p>
<textarea name="data1" style="width:100px;height:20px;"></textarea> 
</div>

<div id=city>   <p>city:</p>  
<textarea name="data2" style="width:200px;height:20px;"></textarea>
</div>

<div id=country>   <p>country:</p>  
<textarea name="data3" style="width:100px;height:20px;"></textarea>
</div>
<br>
<input id=bouton1 type="button" onclick="javascript:generateTable()" value="Generate 
table"/>
```

**And that’s the table generated in a different "body":**

```
<body><center>

<p>Table:</p>
<div id="excel_table1"></div>

</center></body>
```

Can Anyone help? The answer might be super easy, but I'm just trying to learn on the fly and know not much about JS! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out! :D

Here's the script that takes data from multiple textareas and put it in different columns of the same table:

```
<script src="jquery-3.5.0.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>  
         <script>

function generateTable() {
     var n=1;
     var rows=[];
     var lng=0;
    $('textarea').each(function(){
      var data = $(this).val();
      var rowData = data.split("\n");
      rows[n] = rowData;
      lng = rowData.length;
      n++;
    })
     var table = $('<table />');
               k=0;
               while (k < lng) {
               var row = $('<tr />');
                    for(var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {

                    var singleRow = rows[i];

                          row.append('<td>'+singleRow[k]+'</td>')

                    }
                        table.append(row);
                k++;
              }

        $('#excel_table1').append(table);

}    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There can only be one `<body>` element on your page. So you would need to place both the textareas and the table in the same body element.

The problem with your script was that you created the table and appended it to your div for each textarea. You need to do this before and after iterating over the textareas.

I've created a snippet changing just that. Hope this helps!

```js
function generateTable() {
  var table = $('<table></table>');
  $('textarea').each(function() {
    var data = $(this).val();
    console.log(data);
    var rows = data.split("\n");

    for (var y in rows) {
      var cells = rows[y].split("\t");
      var row = $('<tr />');
      for (var x in cells) {
        row.append('<td>' + cells[x] + '</td>');
      }
      table.append(row);
    }
  })
  $('#excel_table1').append(table);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id=street>
  <p>street:</p>
  <textarea name="data1" style="width:100px;height:20px;"></textarea>
</div>

<div id=city>
  <p>city:</p>
  <textarea name="data2" style="width:200px;height:20px;"></textarea>
</div>

<div id=country>
  <p>country:</p>
  <textarea name="data3" style="width:100px;height:20px;"></textarea>
</div>
<br>
<input id="bouton1" type="button" onclick="generateTable()" value="Generate 
table" />

<p>Table:</p>
<div id="excel_table1"></div>
```

Comment: Thank's @RobbeVP, that helped understanding more of the structure! But I actually still get (even in the snippet): Street/City/country/ in the same column of the table, not in different columns as I need them to be. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want to achieve. Do you want this info in the same row, but different columns? Or...?

Comment: I actually needed to put all the data copied/pasted (already in rows) from one textarea into one column, and do the same thing for the others textareas in two others columns. I just figured it out this morning, so I posted the answer with the right script just below! Thanks for the help :)